# How to compile assembly code in DOSBox on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, assembly, masm, dosbox

Our teacher wants us to compile with MASM, but I know it doesn't work on OS X. He said also, we shouldn't use Turbo Assembler. What should I do? May I compile it somewhere and then open it in DOSBox? If yes, tell me please, where should I do this.

Comment: Unless you find a really old version of MASM that works under MS-DOS you can't run it under DOSBox. A version that old will have differences from modern versions of MASM that might cause problem if you teacher expects you to be using modern MASM.

Comment: You could download a [16-bit version of MASM](http://www.phatcode.net/downloads.php?id=175) and then install it inside a DOSBox environment. You then run MASM inside the DOSBox environment.

Comment: Of course as Ross points out if you are targeting something other than 16-bit code then the suggested method won't work. You might be able to get a 32-bit version of _MASM_ to work under [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/)

Comment: Thanks guys! Finally it works. :)